# On click of text , i want the list view builder to show that container of that specific text

Tags: android, flutter, listview, text, scrollcontroller

I am implementing scrollcontroller flutter according to A , B , C text .
and using a listview builder on same page to show all data of that A.
For example clicking on A , screen will scroll automatically and will be shown container having names starting with A eg Angel , ANger etc.

if i click on B then it should scroll to container containing Basket , Boal etc.

how to implement this functionality!
using scrollcontroller or should i use hash map

My ui looks like :-

1. I have a list of alphabets A to Z.
2. Below that i have list of containers in a way that container A contains names starting with A , B contains names starting with B.
3. I want on click of list of alphabet's alphabet , my screen should scroll down to that specific container containing alphabets !

Comment: So you want to scroll list view on flutter on click?

Comment: [alphabet_scroll_view](https://pub.dev/packages/alphabet_scroll_view) or [alphabetical_search](https://github.com/thanikad/alphabetical_search) may help you

Comment: yes , on click of an alphabet it should go there

Comment: alphabet scroll view is different